# Python Scrapy print start_url or variable in start_url

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Trying to yield the "number" or the maybe get the `start_url` then parse the `start_url` to get the number:

```
class EbaypriceSpider(Spider):
    name = "ebayprice"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ebay.com"]
    start_urls = []
    with open('Numbers.csv', 'rb') as omcan_numbers:
        number_list = csv.reader(omcan_numbers)
        for number in number_list: 
            start_urls.append('http://www.ebay.com/sch/Omcan' + str(number))


    def parse(self, response):
        # DO stuff then call parse_page2


    def parse_page2(self, response):
        print number
        # I want to get get start url or number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `start_urls` use the `start_requests` method:

```
class EbaypriceSpider(Spider):
    name = "ebayprice"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ebay.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('Numbers.csv','rb') as omcan_numbers:
            number_list = csv.reader(omcan_numbers)
            for number in number_list:
                url = 'http://www.ebay.com/sch/Omcan'+ str(number)
                yield Request(url, meta={'start_url':url}, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # DO stuff then call parse_page2
        ...
        # keep passing the `meta` argument from previous request
        yield Request(some_other_url, meta=response.meta, callback=self.parse_page2)

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        # i want to get get start url or number
        start_url = response.meta['start_url']
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Any idea how to get "number" with out praseing the start_url? response.meta['number'] did not seem to work

Comment: `meta` is a dictionary, it will contain the things you are adding. add it on `start_requests` like `meta={'start_url':url, 'some_number':number}`

Comment: WOW NICE THANKYOU

Comment: np, please accept the answer if it helped you. Remember to learn more about the [`meta` parameter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) which is basically a way to communicate between callbacks